# Access_token works in localhost not in server

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am using the following code in my application to check if some headers are provided .The code works fine in localhost but not when the application is deployed to server  . Basically I am trying to check if headers are present in the request. On the server , I keep getting invalid request . When I pass accesstoken instead of access_token , the request goes through successfully .  So by changing `if ((request.headers.access_token && request.headers.refresh_token && request.headers.id_token) || request.headers.token)` 
to

The code works , my question is why is this happening

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Path = require('path');
const axios = require('axios');

    var tokenValidation = function (request, reply) {


            if ((request.headers.access_token && request.headers.refresh_token && request.headers.id_token) || request.headers.token) {

                if (request.headers.access_token != undefined) {
                   //do something
                    }
                    else {
                        return reply.continue();
                    }

                } else
                    return reply.continue();
            } 
            else {
                var err = Boom.badRequest(‘Invalid request.');
                reply(err);
            }
        }

        server.ext('onRequest', tokenValidation);
```

Comment: You npm installed on the server, correct?

Comment: What is `server` ? Please include `require` statements.

Comment: You'll want to provide an example of the request (with headers) that works on localhost but not on the server.

Comment: const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Path = require('path');
const build = require('../build.json');
var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');

const Boom = require('boom');
const axios = require('axios');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var logger=require('./fleet-api/logger');

Its a simple GET request , contains headers

Comment: is the server running the same version of node

Comment: Yes it is running same version of node.js

Comment: so... implement some better reporting on said invalid request. Without knowing why it's going to invalid request, your guess is as good as mine. What part of that conditional isn't passing?

Comment: (request.headers.access_token && request.headers.refresh_token && request.headers.id_token) this condition is faling . The funny thing is if i just supply a token , it works and goes through

Comment: ... so doesnt that tell you something about the token?

Comment: I am using the exact same headers in both requests , so not sure what might be causing the issue

Comment: So by changing `if ((request.headers.access_token && request.headers.refresh_token && request.headers.id_token) || request.headers.token)` 
to 
    if ((request.headers.accesstoken && request.headers.refreshtoken && request.headers.idtoken) || request.headers.token)

The code works , my question is why is the server ignoring underscores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Missing (disappearing) HTTP Headers
If you do not explicitly set underscores_in_headers on;, NGINX will silently drop HTTP headers with underscores (which are perfectly valid according to the HTTP standard). This is done in order to prevent ambiguities when mapping headers to CGI variables as both dashes and underscores are mapped to underscores during that process.**

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#missing--28disappearing-29-http-headers

We have to explicitly underscores_in_headers on in NGINX , else they will be ignored